# Enable keyboard enter key as a submit button in python gui

Tags: python, user-interface, key, submit, enter

I just want to enable keyboard enter key  to function as a submit button in  Python `gui` for a simple windows desktop application.

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import ttk  # for treeview
import keyboard
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After typing on entry box you click submit button. As an alternative I want the Enter key to do the same as button click event. hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

> After typing on entry box you click submit button. As an alternative I
> want the Enter key to do the same as button click event

You need to add function to accept parameter. And pass the function to `bind`.

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
 

root = tk.Tk()
        
new_entry = tk.Entry(root)
new_entry.pack()

def enter(event=None):
    print(new_entry.get())
    
root. bind('<Return>', enter)    
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot everything.

Comment: When enter key worked the submit button not,

Comment: You don't needed button. It is widely used '<Return>'. So you wanted button too?